# QuestDB - ingest data from Telegraf

Tags: questdb

When using JSON Web Key as authentication method for ILP, is there any way to ingest data into QuestDB from Telegraf?

The authentication part is not covered in the docs.

```
https://questdb.io/docs/third-party-tools/telegraf/
https://questdb.io/docs/reference/api/ilp/overview/
https://questdb.io/docs/reference/api/ilp/authenticate/
```

Thanks in advance for your help and tips to solve this!

Answer (score 2):

As of QuestDB 7.3.3 this is not supported.

There is an open [feature request](https://github.com/questdb/questdb/issues/3868) in QuestDB. From the feature request:

> I'd like to feed data from Telegraf to QuestDB over ILP. This currently works only when ILP does not have any authentication configured. I'd like to use the plugin together with ILP authentication. This likely requires a custom Telegraf plugin, it should not be too difficult to implement one.